# How to update apps through iTunes?

Tags: itunes

I have iTunes 12.3.3.17 on Windows 7 and I want to update an app through iTunes.

All the tutorials I have found are for iTunes 11, where there is a clear button at the bottom. This is not the case with iTunes 12. How can I update an app via iTunes?

Comment: Why can't you update the app thru the App Store?  That's how apps are normally updated.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Ask Different!

In iTunes, go to the upper left corner, and find the bar that shows icons for things such as Music, Movies, etc. Click the button with the three dots, and you should see Apps. From there, you'll see a button that says "Updates." Click that, then Update All Apps. For more information, look [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7227380?start=0).